# What is the different deploy your web site under the Sites vs Default Web Site

Tags: iis, web

When you deploy your web site project to IIS, what is the different between deploy it under the Sites vs Default Web Site? Which one is better? I figured all the sites under the Default Web Site shared the same "parent" application pool, DefaultAppPool (by default)? Furthermore, if the identity of the DefaultAppPool is NetworkService, and the web site under the Default Web Site run its own application pool with a differnt identity, then which one will take effect? Will it affect my access to certain network drive, directory, files, ect?